# FLUTTER: fetch markers from firestore docs to google map but doesn't display

Tags: flutter, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-firestore, google-maps-markers, marker

I'm getting markers from a collection named "markers" in firestore and trying to display them on the Google Map. First I just show de GoogleMap and have a FAB and Im looking for onPressed display all de markers on the firestore collection.

The code reads documents but wont show them. Can't find my error here. Please any advise is well receive.

Initial code here...

```
class ClientMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ClientMapState createState() => _ClientMapState();
}

class _ClientMapState extends State<ClientMap> {
  final CameraPosition _kUbicacionVerdi =
      CameraPosition(target: LatLng(-12.090, -77.043), zoom: 16);

  BitmapDescriptor pinLocationIcon;

  Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  Set<Marker> _markers2 = {};
```

Here I fetch firestore data and init markers >>

```
 populateMarkers() { 
    _firestore.collection('markers').getDocuments().then((docs) {
      if (docs.documents.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < docs.documents.length; ++i) {
          // markers.add(docs.documents[i].data);
          initMarker(docs.documents[i].data, docs.documents[i].documentID);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  initMarker(request, requestId) {
    var p = request['position'];
    var markerIdVal = requestId;
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);

    setState(() {
      _markers2.add(Marker(
        markerId: markerId,
        position: LatLng(p['position'].latitude, p['position'].longitude),
        icon: pinLocationIcon,
        visible: true,
      ));
    });
  }
```

finally the build method>>

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.normal, 
              initialCameraPosition: _kUbicacionVerdi,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
              myLocationEnabled: true, 
              markers: _markers2,
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated(mapController),

            ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            populateMarkers();
            print(_markers2);
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ));
  }
```

Any ideas of where's my error?

Comment: the line for onMapCreated goes like this.... (GoogleMapController _mapController) {
                _mapController.setMapStyle(jsonEncode(mapStyle))   // mapStyle is a const in other dart file, it just changes the style and works fine.

Comment: is this working with default marker icons? (without pass any icon to marker), I think BitmapDescriptor need to be assigned before the map created and markers added

Comment: and can you share the BitmapDescriptor part from your code

Comment: @ciplionat  void setCustomMapPin() async {
    pinLocationIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5), "assets/images/gota.png");
  }